# Is it possible to find requests in Request Pending Queue on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Before a request gets served by an instance it comes in Request Queue and after that Request Scheduler watches if any instance is free, if its free then Request Scheduler put that request on the free instance so that it can get served.

Please let me know if my understand is right for request getting served by app engine instance (frontend/backend instance) ?

Is it possible to find out how many request are pending in the Pending Request Queue ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to find out how many request are pending in the Pending Request Queue ?

Such functionality is currently not described anywhere and it isn't possible.

> Scheduler watches if any instance is free, if its free then Request Scheduler put that request on the free instance so that it can get served.

To be more precise, scheduler watches if there is any instance able to process another request at the moment, so the instance doesn't have to be *free*. If there is not available instance then the request will wait to be assigned in the Pending Queue up to 10s. After 10s the request is canceled.

You could observe the requests that never got out of the pending queue, as an example, by setting following custom filters in Stackdriver Logging:

> labels.clone_id=""
>
> protoPayload.latency>="10s"

Comment: Is there any document describing the Request Scheduler, Pending Queue and the thresholds (like this 10s) more in-depth than the [How requests are handled](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-requests-are-handled) doc?